# $n \in \mathbb{N}$ has at least 73 two-digit divisors. Prove that one of the divisors is 60.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, prime-factorization

$n \in \mathbb{N}$ has at least 73 two-digit divisors.

I have these questions:

a) How can I prove that one of the two-digit divisors must be number 60?

b) How can I find a natural number that has $\mathbb{exactly}$ 73 two-digit divisors?

Comment: What on earth does "one of the two-digit divisors must be number" mean?

Comment: @fleablood typo, I am sorry, fixed

Comment: Why are you asking about b?

Comment: @fleablood there could be come divisors overlapping, just looking if someone comes up with a proper way to do it, or whether it's just a trial-error kind of a thing ;)

Comment: There will definitely be overlap.  Of the $73$ divisors very few pairs will be relatively prime.  If $n= \prod p_i^{a_i}$ it will have exactly $\prod (a_i + 1)$ divisors.  But some of those will have $1$ digit (at least $2,3,4,6,5$ are divisors) and certainly many $3$ digits or more.  I expect exactly $73$ will be extremely difficult to find.

Comment: Or we could do what rogerl did......  (don't have to take the product.... any common multiple without that isn't a multiple of the chosen primes will do... such as the least common multiple....)

Answer (score 8):

You're asking a wrong type of question in this kind of exercise. Use [Dirichlet's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) instead:

1. Among those 73 divisors, there must be at least one that is divisible by 4.
2. Among 73 divisors at least one must be divisible by 3.
3. There are 18 two-digit numbers divisible by 5 ($10, 15, 20, 25, \dots, 90, 95$ and there are 90 two-digit numbers overall. If we remove those divisible by 5, there are 72 left, so among those 73, there must be the one divisible by 5.

Since the number is divisible by 3, 4 and 5, it's also divisible by $3*4*5=60$.

Comment: Yeah.... I'm a slow typer... and a careless one.  I'll delete the comment.

Comment: there are 90 two digit numbers, 10 to 99...

Comment: @WillJagy thank you

Answer (score 2):

For (b), you need to remove 17 two-digit numbers from the 90 available. Remove 9 of the 10 primes between 50 and 100, and then remove the four primes between 34 and 50 together with their doubles. For example, remove
$$37, 74, 41, 82, 43, 86, 47, 94, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89.$$
Clearly the product of the remaining two-digit numbers is not divisible by any of these, so it has exactly 73 two-digit divisors.

Edit: changed after reading @WillJagy's comment. I miscounted the number of possible two-digit divisors.

Comment: I did your recipe, single change owing to the missing 47, took out 41, 82, 43, 86, 47, 94, 53,...   and got 74 two digit divisors. Meanwhile, I took LCM, the full number is 224403121196654400 =  2^6 3^4 5^2 7^2 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37

Comment: I may have it, a prime from 37 t0 47 counts for 2 divisors of two digits each, whil a prime from 53 to 97 counts for 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are $90$ two digit numbers  $45$ of then are odd.  So at least $73 -45= 28$ of $73$ divisors are even. So $n$ has an even divisor and is even.

If the $45$ even two digit numbers $22$ of then them are divisible by $4$.  So at least $28-22=6$ of these divisors are divisible by $4$ so $n$ is divisible by $4$.

Note:  of the $22$ numbers divisible $4$, $11$ of them are divisible by $8$.  But we only need $6$ divisible by $4$ and none of those need to be divisible by $8$ so we do not need any divisible by $8$.

Of the $90$ two digit numbers $30$ of the are divisible by $3$ and $60$ of them aren't.  So there are of the $73$ divisors, at least, $73-60=13$ of them are divisible by $3$.  So $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Of the  $90$ two digit numbers $18$ of them are divisible by $5$ and $72$ of the aren't.  So there are at least $73-72=1$ of the divisors divisible by $5$.  So $n$ is divisible by $5$.

So $n$ is divisible by $4$ and $3$ and $5$ so $n$ is divisible by $\operatorname{lcm}{4,3,5) = 60$.

......

Give me a moment to think about b).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by roger1, this slight change makes it work:
$$   588300074488526400 \; = \; 2^6  \cdot 3^4 \cdot  5^2 \cdot  7^2 \cdot  11 \cdot  13 \cdot  17 \cdot  19 \cdot  23 \cdot  29 \cdot  31 \cdot  97   $$

---

```
588300074488526400 =  2^6 3^4 5^2 7^2 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 97


10    count 1
11    count 2
12    count 3
13    count 4
14    count 5
15    count 6
16    count 7
17    count 8
18    count 9
19    count 10
20    count 11
21    count 12
22    count 13
23    count 14
24    count 15
25    count 16
26    count 17
27    count 18
28    count 19
29    count 20
30    count 21
31    count 22
32    count 23
33    count 24
34    count 25
35    count 26
36    count 27
38    count 28
39    count 29
40    count 30
42    count 31
44    count 32
45    count 33
46    count 34
48    count 35
49    count 36
50    count 37
51    count 38
52    count 39
54    count 40
55    count 41
56    count 42
57    count 43
58    count 44
60    count 45
62    count 46
63    count 47
64    count 48
65    count 49
66    count 50
68    count 51
69    count 52
70    count 53
72    count 54
75    count 55
76    count 56
77    count 57
78    count 58
80    count 59
81    count 60
84    count 61
85    count 62
87    count 63
88    count 64
90    count 65
91    count 66
92    count 67
93    count 68
95    count 69
96    count 70
97    count 71
98    count 72
99    count 73
Sat Jan 11 15:07:58 PST 2020
```

---